# Horizontal Sum for dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot-table

I'm currently trying to get the horizontal sum of a report. Currently using dynamic query and a pivot table. Below is my code

declare @cols nvarchar(max)
declare @pvt_cols nvarchar(max)
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)

```
select @cols= Coalesce(@cols+',','')
    + 'Coalesce([' +MonthYR+ '],0) AS [' + MonthDescription +'] '
            ,@pvt_cols=coalesce(@pvt_cols +',','') +' ['+[MonthYR] +']' 
from @Calendar 
where CASDT between '20110401' and '20111230' (generates column with month headers)

print @cols     
print @pvt_cols
print '--------------------'


Set @sqlquery='Select ProdDesc,'+@cols + ',Total
            from (Select    ProdDesc, 
                    MonthYr, 
                    NetAmount,
                    SUM(NetAmount ) over (partition by ProdDesc) as Total 
            from #Comtempt1
             ) as dat 
                    pivot(
            SUM(NetAmount) for MonthYr in 
            (' + @pvt_cols + '))pvt'

print @sqlquery

exec sp_executesql @sqlquery
```

I am able to get the total but it shows the total for the whole records whereas I only need to get the total depending on the dates entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max) declare @pvt_cols nvarchar(max) declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)
declare @total nvarchar(max)
select @cols= Coalesce(@cols+',','')
    + 'Coalesce([' +MonthYR+ '],0) AS [' + MonthDescription +'] '
            ,@pvt_cols=coalesce(@pvt_cols +',','') +' ['+[MonthYR] +']' 
            ,@total= Coalesce(@total+'+','') + 'Coalesce([' +MonthYR+ '],0)'
from @Calendar 
where CASDT between '20110401' and '20111230' (generates column with month headers)

print @cols     
print @pvt_cols
print '--------------------'


Set @sqlquery='Select ProdDesc,'+@cols + ',' + @Total + ' Total
            from (Select    ProdDesc, 
                    MonthYr, 
                    NetAmount,
                    SUM(NetAmount ) over (partition by ProdDesc) as Total 
            from #Comtempt1
             ) as dat 
                    pivot(
            SUM(NetAmount) for MonthYr in 
            (' + @pvt_cols + '))pvt'

print @sqlquery

exec sp_executesql @sqlquery
```

Comment: I've tried your query but it only duplicates the value from the @cols I need to add a Total column. 
here is a screenshot http://i85.photobucket.com/albums/k42/esr0159/sss-1.jpg

Comment: Well, where's the "Total" column in the screenshot? What did `print @sqlquery` show?

Comment: i needed to add that, anyways I was able to create a new query now. uh the new "@sqlquery" you posted duplicates the values from the @cols column. nonetheless thanks for your help :)